# Error with boost::thread::try_join_for() function

Tags: linux, boost, c++14, boost-thread, gcc5

I am trying to use `boost::thread::try_join_for()` function but I am getting the following compile time error:

> "'class boost::thread' has no member named 'try_join_for'

I am able to use `boost::thread::timed_join()` function. But I don't want to use this function as this function has been deprecated.

My current boost version is 1.66.0. Previously, I had 1.61.0 and I thought maybe there is a bug, so I updated it to 1.66.0.  But still the same problem.

I also looked into the header file `<boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp>`. And maybe it seemed like macro `BOOST_THREAD_USES_CHRONO` is not defined. Although, my IDE (QT) is able to detect it that the macro is defined because if I change it to `#if !defined BOOST_THREAD_USES_CHRONO` then the followed block code gets faded.

My build command is as follows:

> ./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=gcc
>
> ./bjam -d0 -a toolset=gcc-custom address-model=64 architecture=x86 instruction-set=nocona variant=release threading=multi link=static
>   stage

I could even see in the build output that chrono component is being built. Following is the partial output:

```
- atomic                   : building
- chrono                   : building
- container                : building
- context                  : building
- coroutine                : building
- date_time                : building
- exception                : building
- fiber                    : building
- filesystem               : building
- graph                    : building
- graph_parallel           : building
- iostreams                : building
- locale                   : building
- log                      : building
- math                     : building
- mpi                      : building
- program_options          : building
- python                   : building
- random                   : building
- regex                    : building
- serialization            : building
- signals                  : building
- stacktrace               : building
- system                   : building
- test                     : building
- thread                   : building
- timer                    : building
- type_erasure             : building
- wave                     : building
```

Am I missing anything? 
I am building on Linux. And My compiler version is gcc-5.4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like Wandbox supports by Boost 1.66 yet, but it compiles happily with Boost 1.65.1:

- GCC 5.4, Boost 1.65.1 https://wandbox.org/permlink/WlY123MQc8LpnAq3
- GCC 7.2, Boost 1.65.1 https://wandbox.org/permlink/QrW0bV00fG1sldpj

In short, I'd second-guess the IDE's intellisense diagnostics, and simply check, e.g.

```
#ifndef BOOST_THREAD_USES_CHRONO
    std::cout << "Yay\n";
#else
    std::cout << "Nay\n";
#endif
```

Comment: Yhea, I tried that and it seems that `BOOST_THREAD_USES_CHRONO` macro is undefined, which is kind of strange. Maybe I did something wrong in the build script. I will check it again and post the update.